# Android $_POST is empty at server?

Tags: android, http-post

I  am writing an httppost on android but on the server side, the $_Post is empty, I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I used.

```
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(type, login));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", tag));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);
```

The php code

```
<?php
    print_r(array_values($_POST));
```

Comment: You should also show the PHP part

Answer (score 0):

check your url.
don't forget http:
"http://yoursite.com" 
check response code to be 200:

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() ==200
```